SEO meta tags are loading but preview didn't work when we share link to social media platforms in next js
I am working on generating meta tags for product details page to show the preview when the link is shared on social media platforms, i can see the tags are loading but still i can't see preview according to data that is passed.


 export async function generateMetadata({ params }) {
  const productID = params?.id;
 
  const productDetail = await GetProductDetail(productID).catch(() => null);

  const { name,store, description, media } = productDetail.data?.data;
  return {
    title: `${name} | ${store.name}`,
    description: description || "Check out this amazing product!",
    openGraph: {
      title: name || "Product Detail",
      description: description || "Check out this amazing product!",
      images: media?.[0]?.media || "/default-image.jpg", 
      type: "website",
      site_name: "Stocks Maze",
      url:`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_HOST_ADDRESS}/buyer/product-detail/${productID}`
    },
    twitter: {
      card: "summary",
      title: `${name} | ${store.name}` ,
      description: description,
      images: media?.[0]?.media ,

    },
  };
}




First check your shared link using the META SEO inspector to verify your meta tags directly in the browser. Also, ensure you clear cached metadata using tools like the Facebook Sharing Debugger or using Heymeta.
Double-check that the meta tags are server-side rendered and accessible in the page source.
